# Airflow 2 loosely coupling @task return values to receiving @task?

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to write two tasks that have no knowledge of the other. One task returns a dict (via `XComArg`) and I want to pass a single property of that object to the next task. If I pass the entire `XComArg` object, its value is populated as expected. But selecting a single property results in a `None`.

```py
@dag(...):
def _dag():

   @task
   def A(**ctx):
      # ...
      return {'a': 42, 'b': 'B', 'c': 'C'}

   @task
   def B(a, _res, **ctx):
      print('A', a) # >>> A None
      print('RES', _res) # >>> RES {'a': 42, ...}

   res = A()
   B(res['a'])

dag = _dag
```

Ideally, `B` doesn't know where the value for `a` comes from, nor how to get it. Yes, passing all of `res` and having `B` extract what it needs with `res['a']` works, but my goal is loose coupling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See example in https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial_taskflow_api.html

You need to specify 'multiple_outputs=true" in task A

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. The docs say that if the type hint shows a `dict` as a return value, then `multiple_outputs=true` is set automatically. In my case, I did not specify `@task(multiple_outputs=true)` but the task function had a return value type hinted for  a class that extends `TypedDict` (which itself extends `dict`, but I guess Airflow does a "shallow" look up of the return type.

Comment: If that's the case - maybe you can add a PR fixing that - should not be too dificult.

Comment: Absolutely. This is now on my short-term #todo. Cheers!